# Can D2L be used as a LTI Tool Provider as well as Tool Consumer

Tags: desire2learn

Can I use D2L as a Tool Provider as well as Tool consumer? Basically if I want to access some learning objects from one D2L instance  to another D2L instance  - is that possible?

Subrata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently, no: D2L cannot act as an LTI Tool Provider. You may be able to achieve what you describe with a service app running in between two D2L instances, using the Valence APIs to read content objects from one LMS, and write to another LMS; however, in this case, you'd need the service to have user credentials for a user in both instances.